# Why can't I mark this method as static?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a BaseImageView (platform is irrelevant here), which has a property `Effect`, which is a [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) object.

I would like all my commands to implement `IImageEffect`, which has an `static` method `ApplyEffect`, taking an image and returning the image with the effect.

But the compiler complains that I cannot mark an interface method as `static`, but this seems like the logical option (as there is no state information needed for the effect).

I ask this because I would need 100 effect objects to apply 1 effect to 100 different images, while I could get away with passing the class and calling the static method, this would do away with the 100 instances.

Is there a way I can have a static interface, or a way that I can pass a class and have it call the static `ApplyEffect` of that type?

Comment: No, interface members cannot be static. How would the CLR know which implementation you wanted to call, if you called `IImageEffect.ApplyEffect`? (There's an argument for static interface members with generic type arguments, but that's more subtle.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I would pass a class to the `Effect` property, and then call `ApplyEffect` on that class, so it would become `EffectClass.ApplyEffect`. Then it would know what specific class I want to call it on.

Comment: Sorry, this is very hard to understand without a concrete example *in the question*. If you just want a static method that always does the same thing, just put it in a class instead of an interface...

Comment: Are there any reason you are not using an abstract class?

Comment: @MortenToudahl I don't want to instantiate a new instance of the same class each time I use that effect, so I thought I'd make it static, but I just realised that this is why the singleton pattern was invented. I'll go ahead and use that.

Comment: @vrwim I think that is misuse of the singleton pattern. Singletons are for when more than one instance would break the app. ie, two drivers for one piece of hardware running. Like 2 x video card drivers. Or for managing configurations - accessing/updating the same configuration in two different objects could make something go wrong.

Take a look at this, and read the articles linked to too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135347/most-common-examples-of-misuse-of-singleton-class

Comment: @MortenToudahl I have a method that only takes an image and only outputs an image, it wouldn't break the app if I had 2 instances. I just deem it useless to have multiple at the same time. What do you suggest I use? Let it be an interface and just instantiate a new instance each time I use it? Or cache an instance and reuse that one? Or simply use a singleton?

Comment: @vrwim Create a static class just to handle effects? Adhering with the single responsibility principle

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you either make an abstract class where you implement the static method, like you wanted to do with the interface.

It could look like this

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseImageView.ApplyEffect();
        // Or
        EffectClass.ApplyEffect();
    }

}

public abstract class EffectClass
{
    public static void ApplyEffect()
    {
        // Effect of awesomeness
    }
}

public class BaseImageView : EffectClass
{

}
```

Or create a static class to apply the effect with, if you don't want to inherrit from an abstract class.

```
public static class EffectClass
{
    public static void ApplyEffect()
    {
        // Effect of awesomeness
    }
}
```